# Merging datasets with repeat key value

Tags: merge, spss

I am attempting to merge two data sets on an ISOLATE_ID variable. the variable is in list form [Isolate File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXgdI.png) and I am attempting to merge it with another file {Microbiology and add the variable of ISOLATE_NAME from the first file ([Micro File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbeAT.png).
When I do the standard SPSS merge file one-to-many merge based on key values, only the value for the first instance of the ISOTE_ID comes across leaving the rest blank [Example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GvU6.png)
How do I get SPSS to fill in all the un-merged data?
I think I might need to restructure the Isolate File but I'm not sure how.
PLEASE HELP

Tried standard merge one-to-one
When trying one-to-many merge I get the Error #5131

Comment: Please edit your post to add the syntax you used for the actions you describe, this will help us find the problem and offer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax should work for you (sort both datasets and then match them on key):

```
dataset activate Isolate_file.
sort cases by ISOLATE_ID.
dataset activate Macro_file.
sort cases by ISOLATE_ID.
match files /file=* /table=Isolate_file /by ISOLATE_ID.
exe.
```